# Laravel Notifications Listener Is Useless When Implementing the Queue

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5.5

Laravel Version: 5.5.*

PHP Version: 7.1.*

According to the docs [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#notification-events) it should be super simple to subscribe to Notification events. I've followed the steps in the docs, but my Notifications implement `ShouldQueue` and they weren't properly populating the event listener. I'm wonder if the issue seems to be **[in the framework code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php)**.

Notice that in the framework github (linked right above), that `new Events\NotificationSent($notifiable, $notification, $channel, $response)` is only fired from the `sendToNotifiable` function, which in turn is only fired from the `sendNow` function. The `send` function itself, is like this:

```
public function send($notifiables, $notification)
    {
        $notifiables = $this->formatNotifiables($notifiables);

        if ($notification instanceof ShouldQueue) {
            return $this->queueNotification($notifiables, $notification);
        }

        return $this->sendNow($notifiables, $notification);
    }
```

That is, as it reads to me, the event **will not fire** if it is a case of `if ($notification instanceof ShouldQueue) {` as `queueNotification` never triggers an event listener. I assume it goes into the queue and then will need to re-trigger the event, but I don't think this is happening, because my `NotificationSent` listener isn't populated with *any* data from that class constructor.

EventServiceProvider:

```
 protected $listen = [
       'Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\NewNotificationListener',
    ],
```

NewNotificationListener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Jobs\SendEmailForNotifications;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
class NewNotificationListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
  public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
{
Log:info('Notification Listener:'.' '.var_dump($event));
SendEmailForNotifications::dispatch($event->notification)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));   
} 
}
```

`var_dump` here is empty, I get nothing in my log, just `Notification Listener:`.

So my question is, why is this and how can I have a Notification event listener while leveraging the Queue as I need to do. Is it something I am doing wrong or is it the framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer: **Have you restarted your queue worker when you made these modifications?**

The `NotificationSent` on my box is triggered and captured as expected when it's being queued and handled.

---

When Laravel hit this piece of code in `NotificationSender`:

```
if ($notification instanceof ShouldQueue) {
    return $this->queueNotification($notifiables, $notification);
}
```

It queues the notification using the Queue Dispatcher and store it into your queue. And when your worker pick it up, it unserialise the command, and launches `SendQueuedNotifications`. This class will then handle the queued notifications, and handle the queue ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fd88ff8cb242760ad23b7bf547e15a22c8ce73df/src/Illuminate/Notifications/SendQueuedNotifications.php#L55-L58)):

```
public function handle(ChannelManager $manager)
{
    $manager->sendNow($this->notifiables, $this->notification, $this->channels);
}
```

And `ChannelManager` does this ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fca0272e61ee2e2e630a40f42ebe0f3e30e75422/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php#L46-L51)):

```
public function sendNow($notifiables, $notification, array $channels = null)
{
    return (new NotificationSender(
        $this, $this->app->make(Bus::class), $this->app->make(Dispatcher::class))
    )->sendNow($notifiables, $notification, $channels);
}
```

And there you go. The `sendNow` in `NotificationSender` is called. The `NotificationSent` event should be called in this function.

---

**Edit**

This is how I tested it:

1. Make sure your queue has been set up correctly. I use a database queue, with jobs/failed_jobs table combo.
2. Create the file `app/Listeners/TestListener.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Listeners;

   use Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent;

   class TestListener
   {
       public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
       {
           \Log::info(get_class($event));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Edit `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Providers;

   use App\Listeners\TestListener;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent;
   use Laravel\Lumen\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

   class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       /**
        * The event listener mappings for the application.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $listen = [
           NotificationSent::class => [
               TestListener::class
           ]
       ];
   }
   ```
4. Create a dummy notification (send an Hello email):

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Notifications\Users;

   use App\Notifications\Notification;
   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

   class WelcomeNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
   {
       use Queueable;

       public function via($notifiable)
       {
           return [MailChannel::class];
       }

       public function toMail($notifiable)
       {
           return (new MailMessage())
                       ->line('Hello');
       }
   }
   ```
5. **Restart your queue worker**. I simply restart my `php artisan queue:work`.
6. Send the notification

   ```
   $user->notify(new WelcomeNotification());
   ```
7. Check `laravel.log`, you should have the class name of `NotificationSent` printed there.

   ```
   [2018-03-06 09:51:02] production.INFO: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent
   ```

Comment: When you say The `NotificationSent` on my box is triggered and captured as expected when it's being queued and handled are you able to populate the `$event` in the listener `handle()` function?

Comment: Yes, I get an instance of `NotificationSent` event in the first parameter of `handle`.

Comment: Just for your info, I did `var_dump($event)` and it prints the output in my console which runs the queue, but not in laravel log. Try just do this: `Log:info('Notification Listener:'.' '.var_dump($event->channel));`, for eg.

Comment: Doesn't work, no matter what I log, `$event` or a property thereof. 

Comment: Can you post your code so I can copy it exactly and see if it works... maybe something in my enviornment is wrong...

Comment: @SummerDeveloper added steps on how I did it :)

Comment: Thanks, I use the notifiable facade rather than the trait... wonder if that makes any difference...

Comment: Shouldn't be any different