# Chaining a Laravel job to a notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Suppose to I want to write a log after a notification is successfully sent. I'd expect this to work, but it never executes the job in the chain after notifying:

```
$user->notify((new SendSomeEmail($content))->chain([
    new LogEmail($user, $content)
]));
```

No errors are triggered.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: did you try php artisan queue:work command?

Comment: Both the notification and the chained job are on the `sync` queue so they should both run immediately.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/illuminate/notifications/blob/master/RoutesNotifications.php as you can see, notify method returns void. I think that's why 'chain' method is not being triggered

What you can do is register listeners for this event in your EventServiceProvider like laravels document says:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#notification-events

here there is an example how to do this:
[Laravel Notifications Listener Is Useless When Implementing the Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101402/laravel-notifications-listener-is-useless-when-implementing-the-queue)